# JPA Multilingual sorting

Tags: java, oracle, sorting, jpa

Recently I am working on a bilingual project and for some reference tables I need to sort the data. But because it is bilingual, the data is coming from different languages (in my case English and French) and I like to sort them all together, for example, `Île` comes before `Inlet`.

Ordinary `Order By` will put `Île` at the end of the list. I finally came up with using `nativeQuery` and sort the data using database engine's function (in oracle is about using [`NLS_SORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm))

But I am tight with database engine and version, so for example if I change my database to `postgres` then the application will break. I was looking for native JPA solution (if exists) or any other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

To archive this, without use native query JPA definition, I just can see two ways:

1. Create a DB view which includes *escaped/translated* columns based on DB functions. So, the DB differences will be on the `create view` sentence. You can define a *OneToOne* relation property to original entity.
2. Create extra column which stores the *escaped* values and sort by it. The application can perform the *escape/translate* before store data in DB using *JPA Entity Listeners* or in the persist/merge methods.

Good luck!

Comment: Like the idea. But I am still looking for more JPA-ish solution